# Robotframework run for x amount of minutes

Tags: robotframework

Im trying to run a test that is repeated for x amount of minutes.
My idea for the keyword:

```
*** Keywords ***

Run test looped
   FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    9999
      Do something
      Exit For Loop If    ${ELAPSED} > ${MAX_DURATION}
   END
```

Im trying to find how to calculate the elapsed time in minutes.
I found the [datetime](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html) type for robotframework but dont know how to get minutes elapsed. How can I get the elapsed time in minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In builtin library there's `Repeat Keyword` - it does exactly what you need:

```
Repeat Keyword  2 minutes   Do Something    arg1    arg2
```

For more info see: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Repeat%20Keyword

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to work with epoch for such use cases - get it before the loop, and compare the current value inside it:

```
Run test looped
   ${start}=    Evaluate    time.time()    time
   FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    9999
      Do something
      ${now}=    Evaluate    time.time()    time
      Exit For Loop If    (${now} - ${start})/60 > ${MAX_DURATION}    # divide the runtime seconds by 60, as ${MAX_DURATION} is in minutes
   END
```